# facebook sdk 4.0 equivalent for Session.StatusCallBack and OpenRequest in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, upgrade

i'm upgrading my android app to Facebook sdk 4.0 and Graph API v2.0and I'd like to know if there are equivalent classes for Session.StatusCallBack and OpenRequest. Here is my code , if anyone could help that'd be great :))

```
    OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_RAW_RESPONSES);

    op.setCallback(statusCallback);

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add(Constants.EMAIL);
    op.setPermissions(permissions);
    Session sess = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(sess);
    sess.openForRead(op.setPermissions(permissions));
```

and the for my StatusCallback

```
Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                                              // Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, graghUserCallback);
                                              if (exception != null) {
                                                  String exMsg = exception.getMessage();
                                                  if (exMsg != null && exMsg.startsWith("ApiException:Error")) {
                                                      isExpireToken = true;
                                                      callbackLogin.onFbLoginError(context.getString(R.string.msgFBConnectFaild));
                                                      String url = Constants.API_FB_TOKEN + myApp.getFbToken();
                                                      Api.sendError(myApp, url, 0, exMsg, Method.POST, null);
                                                  }
                                              }
                                              CommonUsed.showProgressDialog(context.getResources().getString(R.string.waiting), context);
                                              runQueryGetUserProfile(session, ConnectionBase.this.callbackLogin);

                                          }

                                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x) and the [login guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3). Basically, you use the LoginManager to do login, and CallbackManager to register callbacks.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() { ... });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // Somewhere in your on activity to actually do login:
    private void login() {
         LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    }
    ...
}
```